# C# Invoke a method

Tags: c#, methods, invoke

So what I want to do is to invoke a method, should look something like this:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
    UIOperations.CustomizeGrid(radGridView3);
}));
```

Now my problem is that I cannot use `this.invoke` inside a class. How would I invoke that? The method I want to invoke is this:

```
public static void CustomizeGrid(RadGridView Gridview)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Gridview.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Gridview.MasterTemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        Gridview.Columns[i].BestFit();
        Gridview.Columns[i].HeaderTextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

        if (Gridview.Columns[i].HeaderText == "Noter")
        {
            Gridview.Columns["Noter"].MaxWidth = 600;
        }
    }
    // Paint every second row
    Gridview.EnableAlternatingRowColor = true;
    ((GridTableElement)Gridview.TableElement).AlternatingRowColor = Color.Aqua;
    // Set row header column width
    Gridview.TableElement.RowHeaderColumnWidth = 32;
}
```

This is where I want to invoke:

```
public static void ExcelToGrid(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1,RadProgressBar radProgressBar1,RadGridView radGridView3)
    {
        try
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("dataTable");
                DataSet dsSource = new DataSet("dataSet");
                dt.Reset();



                Excel.Workbook ExWorkbook;
                Excel.Worksheet ExWorksheet;
                Excel.Range ExRange;
                Excel.Application ExObj = new Excel.Application();

                ExWorkbook = ExObj.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                ExWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                ExRange = ExWorksheet.UsedRange;

                for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ExRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ExRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();

                string[] columnNames = new String[dt.Columns.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    columnNames[0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ExRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
                {
                    int MaxValue = ExRange.Rows.Count;
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ExRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                    {
                        if ((ExRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                        {
                            dr[Cnum - 1] = (ExRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    //Write progressbar
                    radProgressBar1.Maximum = MaxValue;
                    radProgressBar1.Step = 1;
                    radProgressBar1.Value1 = Rnum;
                    radProgressBar1.Text = "Åbner " + Rnum + "/" + MaxValue;

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }
                //Reset progressbar
                radProgressBar1.Value1 = 0;
                radProgressBar1.Text = "";
                //Close workbook
                ExWorkbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                ExObj.Quit();

                if (radGridView3.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    radGridView3.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { radGridView3.DataSource = dt; }));
                }

                //Disallow sorting
                for (int i = 0; i < radGridView3.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    radGridView3.Columns[i].AllowSort = false;
                }
            }
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                UIOperations.CustomizeGrid(radGridView3);
            }));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add some context about the necessity of `MethodInvoker`; why could you not simply run `UIOperations.CustomizeGrid(radGridView3);` in your context? In any case, `Invoke` should be run is a method on the control whose thread you will want to invoke the method on; probably in your context you have access to that somehow?

Comment: Oh sure, it's because I run it inside a thread. (the appartment state is STA)

Comment: How is the class in which you want to place your first line related to the control?

Comment: I updated the post, hope it helps?

Comment: Try `radProgressBar1.Invoke(...)`.

Comment: @ Enigmativity its not a problem for me to invoke the controls. The problem is to invoke UIOperations.CustomizeGrid(radGridView3);

Comment: You should also remove all of the `catch (Exception ex)` code from your app. It's such a bad anti-pattern. You should only catch exceptions that you can meaningfully recover from. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @ Enigmativity that is not the topic...

Comment: @Taco2 - Please use the `@` notifications when responding to someone.

Comment: @Taco2 - Topic or not it's a suggestion to help your code be better.

Comment: That is not relevant to me, if it were, I would have stated it

Comment: `Invoke` should be called on the control whose thread you are interested in. Which control is that? Just guessing now, but if `ExcelToGrid` happens to be called by the control, then you could simply move the invocation outside of `ExcelToGrid`. If not, you should provide more context.

Comment: That is radgridview3, and what the method I want to invoke does is pretty much just to format the radgridview3 interface paint every 2'and row etc..

Comment: And ExcelToGrid is called by a button to import excel to radgridview3

Comment: `I cannot use this.invoke inside a class` But of course you can! Just not in a static class, where `this` has no meaning. This has a smell of an XY-problem.

Comment: Then how would you suggest handling it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current design where you use a static helper class, you better bring the logic that is needed to decide if [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) need to be called inside that static method so consumers of the method don't have to deal with that. RadGridView is subclassing [Control](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radgridview.htm) so those handy properties are available on instances of a RadGridView.

```
public static void CustomizeGrid(RadGridView Gridview)
{
   // check if Invoke is needed
   if (Gridview.InvokeRequired) 
   {
      // Yes, so invoke on the Control instance that was supplied
      Gridview.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
        // makes the same call but now you''ll be on the UI thread
        CustomizeGrid(Gridview);
       }));
      return;
   } 

   // all your other logic here
}
```

The consumers of that method in your static `UIOperations` class can now simply call

```
UIOperations.CustomizeGrid(radGridView3);
```

without having to worry if they are invoking from the UI thread.